# Ecto - Self reference, has_many through

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have the following User module :

```
  schema "accounts_users" do
    has_many :friendships, Friendship
    has_many :friends, through: [:friendships, :friend]

    timestamps()
  end
```

The Friendship module :

```
  schema "accounts_friendships" do
    belongs_to :user, User
    belongs_to :friend, User

    timestamps()
  end
```

And the Friendship migration :

```
  def change do
    create table(:accounts_friendships) do
      add :user_id, references(:accounts_users, on_delete: :nothing)
      add :friend_id, references(:accounts_users, on_delete: :nothing)

      timestamps()
    end

    create index(:accounts_friendships, [:user_id])
    create index(:accounts_friendships, [:friend_id])
  end
```

I can create a new Friendship between user 1 and user 2 like so :

```
 %Friendship{user_id: 1, friend_id: 2} |> Repo.insert()
```

The behaviour works as expected for user 1 :

```
Repo.all(Ecto.assoc(user1, :friendships)) # => [%Friendship{...}]
Repo.all(Ecto.assoc(user1, :friends)) # => [%User{...}]
```

But not for user 2 :

```
Repo.all(Ecto.assoc(user2, :friendships)) # => []
Repo.all(Ecto.assoc(user2, :friends)) # => []
```

I understand why `friends` can't be found for user 2, but why not the `friendships` ? Is something wrong with the relation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I understand why `friends` can't be found for user 2, but why not the friendships ? Is something wrong with the relation ?

Because `friendships` is only concerned with the `user` field of `Friendship`. Your query searches only for `friendships.user_id = 2`, which does not return anything because the Friendship that was created had `user_id = 1` and `friend_id = 2`.

You can create another relation, say `reverse_friendships`, which will return the friendships where the user is the `friend`, not the `user`:

```
has_many :reverse_friendships, Friendship, foreign_key: :friend_id
```

Now `user1` will have no `reverse_friendships` but `user2` will have a `reverse_friendships` with `user1`.